# How to bind Multiple Buttons in Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

[image]

I want to bind a list of buttons in combo boxes. Each Combobox will contains buttons of one category and so on. As referred in attached image.

Below is my code:

```xml
<ItemsControl x:Name="iNumbersList">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="930"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button  Click="ItemButtonClick"
                 Tag="{Binding ItemTag}"
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 Height="100" Width="300">
                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Text="{Binding ItemDisplayMember}"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

```cs
public class NumberModel
{
    public string ItemDisplayMember { get; set; }
    public object ItemTag { get; set; }
    public string ItemCategory { get; set; }
}
```

How can I group by `ItemCategory` property and bind it on GUI, a `ComboBox` for each `ItemCategory` and then multiple buttons in it?

Comment: Why `ComboBox`? Use [`Expander`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/expander-overview) or customize `TreeView`.

Comment: @aepot ... can you please share me example, in which I can bind a list of Exander controls and each exander control with multiple buttons in it ?

Comment: `Expander` is not items control but wrapper. It only give you expand/collapse feature.

Comment: Are using **MVVM**?

Comment: no mvvm ... @aepot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you don't need a `ComboBox` but [`Expander`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/expander-overview) because the objective is reachable using it. `ComboBox` is needed when you have to filter something inside it or use dropdown displayed above `Window`s content.

I wrote a simple example using [**MVVM**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) programming pattern. There will be many new classes but most of it you need add to the project only once. **Let's go from the scratch!**

1) Create class `NotifyPropertyChanged` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. It needed to make able `Binding` to update the layout dynamically in Runtime.

**NotifyPropertyChanged.cs**

```csharp
public class NotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

2) Create `MainViewModel` class derived from `NotifyPropertyChanged`. It will be used for `Binding` target Properties.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }
}
```

3) Attach `MainViewModel` to `MainWindow`'s `DataContext`. One of ways - doing it in xaml.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

4) Derive the data class `NumberModel` from `NotifyPropertyChanged` and add `OnPropertyChanged` call for each Property. This will give wonderful effect: when you change any Property in runtime, You'll immediately see the changes in UI. **MVVM** Magic called `Binding` :)

**NumberModel.cs**

```csharp
public class NumberModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _itemDisplayMember;
    private object _itemTag;
    private string _itemCategory;

    public string ItemDisplayMember
    { 
        get => _itemDisplayMember;
        set 
        {
            _itemDisplayMember = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public object ItemTag
    {
        get => _itemTag;
        set
        {
            _itemTag = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string ItemCategory
    {
        get => _itemCategory;
        set
        {
            _itemCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

5) When button is clicked I will not handle the `Click` event but call a `Command`. For easy use of Commands I suggest this relaying its logic class (grabbed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern#relaying-command-logic)).

**RelayCommand.cs**

```csharp
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    public void Execute(object parameter) => _execute(parameter);
}
```

6) All ready to fill the `MainViewModel` with code. I've added there a command and some items to collection for test.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```xaml
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<NumberModel> _itemsList;
    private ICommand _myCommand;

    public ObservableCollection<NumberModel> ItemsList
    {
        get => _itemsList;
        set
        {
            _itemsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand MyCommand => _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(parameter =>
    {
        if (parameter is NumberModel number) 
            MessageBox.Show("ItemDisplayMember: " + number.ItemDisplayMember + "\r\nItemTag: " + number.ItemTag.ToString() + "\r\nItemCategory: " + number.ItemCategory);
    }));

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<NumberModel>
        {
            new NumberModel { ItemDisplayMember = "Button1", ItemTag="Tag1", ItemCategory = "Category1" },
            new NumberModel { ItemDisplayMember = "Button2", ItemTag="Tag2", ItemCategory = "Category1" },
            new NumberModel { ItemDisplayMember = "Button3", ItemTag="Tag3", ItemCategory = "Category1" },
            new NumberModel { ItemDisplayMember = "Button4", ItemTag="Tag4", ItemCategory = "Category2" },
            new NumberModel { ItemDisplayMember = "Button5", ItemTag="Tag5", ItemCategory = "Category2" },
            new NumberModel { ItemDisplayMember = "Button6", ItemTag="Tag6", ItemCategory = "Category2" },
            new NumberModel { ItemDisplayMember = "Button7", ItemTag="Tag7", ItemCategory = "Category3" },
            new NumberModel { ItemDisplayMember = "Button8", ItemTag="Tag8", ItemCategory = "Category4" },
            new NumberModel { ItemDisplayMember = "Button9", ItemTag="Tag9", ItemCategory = "Category4" }
        };
    }
}
```

7) **The main answer to your main question is:** use `IValueConverter` to filter the list with requred criteria. I wrote 2 converters. First for Categories, second for Buttons.

**Converters.cs**

```csharp
public class CategoryConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is ObservableCollection<NumberModel> collection)
        {
            List<NumberModel> result = new List<NumberModel>();
            foreach (NumberModel item in collection)
            {
                if (!result.Any(x => x.ItemCategory == item.ItemCategory))
                    result.Add(item);
            }
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ItemGroupConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values[0] is ObservableCollection<NumberModel> collection && values[1] is string categoryName)
        {
            List<NumberModel> result = new List<NumberModel>();
            foreach (NumberModel item in collection)
            {
                if (item.ItemCategory == categoryName)
                    result.Add(item);
            }
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

8) Now everything is ready to fill the markup. I post full markup here to make everything clear.

***Note:*** I faced [Visual Studio 2019 16.5.4 crash](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/973393/xaml-crash-itemscontrol-with-multibinding-and-item.html) while setting a `MultiBinding` in `ItemsSource` and applied the workaround.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1000" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:CategoryConverter x:Key="CategoryConverter"/>
        <local:ItemGroupConverter x:Key="ItemGroupConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList, Converter={StaticResource CategoryConverter}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NumberModel}">
                    <Expander Header="{Binding ItemCategory}">
                        <ItemsControl DataContext="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}">
                            <ItemsControl.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
                                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemGroupConverter}">
                                                <Binding Path="ItemsList"/>
                                                <Binding Path="Header" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Expander}"/>
                                            </MultiBinding>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </ItemsControl.Style>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="930"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NumberModel}">
                                    <Button Tag="{Binding ItemTag}"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                            Height="100" Width="300"
                                            Command="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Red"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold"
                                                   FontSize="25" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                   Text="{Binding ItemDisplayMember}"/>
                                    </Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Job is done with **MVVM**. Enjoy. :)

[image: Screenshot]

P.S. Ah, yes, I forgot to show you the code-behind class. Here it is!

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```csharp
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```